# Calculating the sum of two aggregations with a case clause

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm having difficulty with the syntax of an aggregation that I'm trying to do. I want to calculate a percentage based on the sum of values in one column and the value of a count from another that uses a case when statement all divided by the sum of a third column. My code looks like this:

```
round(sum(tb1.col1) + count(case when tb2.col2 = 1 then 1 ELSE NULL END) / sum(tb1.col3), 2)
```

The data with all tables joined would look something like the following where I've applied the individual aggregations in the code I shared above:

```
tb1.col1 | tb2.col2 | tb1.col3
10        5          50
```

With the above data, I want my code to return (10+5)/(50) = 0.3 but currently my code just returns the same value as tb1.col1 = 10.

Where is an issue in my syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just figured it out - turns out I did not have enough brackets!

round((sum(tb1.col1) + count(case when tb2.col2 = 1 then 1 ELSE NULL END)) / sum(tb1.col3),2)

Comment: Based on your description, I think you also need to change the calculation col2 from count() to sum() based on your problem description,